# Python3 can't install bcrypt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation

When i try to install bcrypt, with `python3 -m pip install bcrypt`,

i get this :

`Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-vhc0qtab/bcrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-v9cb4je7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vhc0qtab/bcrypt
Storing debug log for failure in /home/vkristof/.pip/pip.log

The debug log:

http://pastebin.com/UEa3WEG3

Comment: Thanks,it works. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one of the error messages states, that libffi is missing. on a debian-like system you could try `$ sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev`.